# Getting ImportError: No module named in Python although package is included

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing some testcases in Python. When I import the package shown below in a testcase, I do not get any errors. But when I run the testcase from the command line, I am getting errors as if the package has not been imported.  The following is the command line:

```
python my_test.py
```

The resulting error:

```
File "my_test.py", line 11, in <module>   from test1.test2.main import
*   ImportError: No module named test1.test2.main
```

Comment: What is the directory structure of `test1.test2` ? Do you have `__init__.py` files in each directory to show them as packages?

Comment: Actually, when run the testcase from pycharm ide, i am able to run successfully, but when i run from command line showing error like above

Comment: What's the current directory for the command line?

Comment: In that case, pycharm will have a different `PYTHONPATH` than what you have on your command line.